# sort numerically based on the first column

Tags: linux, bash, sorting

I have a tsv separated file, which i try to sort.
I use `sort -k1,1n,` in order to sort numerically, on the first column.

but the result i get is the following, which is not what i wanted:

```
    061     data1
    2305    data2
    4080    data3
    9251    data4
    11844   data5
    238 data6
    264 data7
    33940   data8
    439 data9
    5640    otherdata
    682 help
    1264    moredata
```

expected output:

```
    061     data1
    238     data6
    264     data7
    439     data9
    682     help
    1264    moredata        
    2305    data2
    4080    data3
    5640    otherdata
    9251    data4
    11844   data5
    33940   data8
```

Comment: sort -k1 -n filename should do what you need?

Comment: Please post the contents of your source file

Comment: you may use as source the output i have posted, and say i wanted to get the expected output as a result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sort` reads from `stdin` and command-line as well. Thus if you have a file you can:

```
sort < file
# or
sort file
```

if you want sort based on first column you can:

```
sort -k1 < file
```

But if fact it does affect the output since by default it does not care about numerical order. Thus you should add `-n` option:

```
  -n, --numeric-sort          compare according to string numerical value
```

and doing it like:

```
sort -k1 -n < file
```

it outputs:

```
061     data1
238 data6
264 data7
439 data9
682 help
1264    moredata
2305    data2
4080    data3
5640    otherdata
9251    data4
11844   data5
33940   data8
```

and if you provide it with `-r` it print in reverse order:

```
33940   data8
11844   data5
9251    data4
5640    otherdata
4080    data3
2305    data2
1264    moredata
682 help
439 data9
264 data7
238 data6
061     data1
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using:

```
sort -n  Input_file
```

Or you need to have equal space between the values then following may help you in same.

```
sort -n  Input_file | awk '{$1=$1} 1' OFS="\t"
```

OR

```
sort -n  Input_file | column -t
```

Comment: my file is already tab separated, so i think sort -n will do. sort -n how can i be sure, it sorts only on the first column?

Comment: Why does it matter? Your sample data doesn't show any field where the first field is identical for two lines. Why is it unacceptable in this case to also sort on the second field?

Comment: the sample data i posted, doesnot cover the data i may have in a huge file. The question was clear Sort on column 1.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `$'\t'` as a field separator:

```
$ cat file.tsv 
    061 data1
    2305    data2
    4080    data3
    9251    data4
    11844   data5
    238 data6

$ sort -t $'\t' -n  file.tsv 
    061 data1
    238 data6
    2305    data2
    4080    data3
    9251    data4
    11844   data5
```

Answer (score 0):

sort -k1 -n -t $'\t' input_file.tsv